# OpenVINO failed to set Blob with FP16 precision not corresponding to user input precision

Tags: python, openvino

I commanded `--data_type FP16` to confirm I could use FP16 precision when I was generating IR format files.

```
python mo_tf.py --saved_model_dir C:\Users\Hsien\Desktop\OCT\saved_model --input_shape [1,256,256,3] --data_type FP16
```

But I got an error message when I tried to execute my inference engine code with **FP16** precision and device assignation was **MYRIAD** or **GPU**.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hsien\Desktop\OCT\test.py", line 27, in <module>
    inference_request.set_blob(blob_name=input_blob_name, blob=input_blob)
  File "ie_api.pyx", line 1438, in openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.InferRequest.set_blob
RuntimeError: [ PARAMETER_MISMATCH ] Failed to set Blob with precision not corresponding to user input precision
```

Here comes my inference engine code

```
from openvino.inference_engine import IECore, Blob, TensorDesc
import cv2
import numpy as np

IMG_PATH = r"C:\Users\Hsien\Desktop\OCT\input_crop.jpg"
XML_PATH = r"C:\Users\Hsien\Desktop\OCT\saved_model\saved_model.xml"
BIN_PATH = r"C:\Users\Hsien\Desktop\OCT\saved_model\saved_model.bin"

ie_core_handler = IECore()
network = ie_core_handler.read_network(model=XML_PATH, weights=BIN_PATH)
executable_network = ie_core_handler.load_network(network, device_name='MYRIAD', num_requests=1)
inference_request = executable_network.requests[0]

image = cv2.imread(IMG_PATH)
re_img = cv2.resize(src=image, dsize=(256, 256))
input_data = np.expand_dims(np.transpose(re_img, (2, 0, 1)), 0).astype(np.float16)
tensor_description = TensorDesc(precision="FP16", dims=(1, 3, 256, 256), layout='NCHW')
input_blob = Blob(tensor_description, input_data)

input_blob_name = next(iter(inference_request.input_blobs))
inference_request.set_blob(blob_name=input_blob_name, blob=input_blob)
inference_request.infer()
output_blob_name = next(iter(inference_request.output_blobs))
output = inference_request.output_blobs[output_blob_name].buffer
print(output)
```

And it can work with **FP32** precision and device assignation is **CPU**, which I only change the following three lines.

```
executable_network = ie_core_handler.load_network(network, device_name='CPU', num_requests=1)
input_data = np.expand_dims(np.transpose(re_img, (2, 0, 1)), 0).astype(np.float32)
tensor_description = TensorDesc(precision="FP32", dims=(1, 3, 256, 256), layout='NCHW')
```

My environment is Windows 11 with openvino_2021.4.752 version.

And my devices are Intel® Core™ i7-11700K with Intel® UHD Graphics 750 and Intel® Neural Compute Stick 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you encountered: `Failed to set Blob with precision not corresponding to user input precision` was due to the input precision is set to FP32 in default. Refer to [Step 2. Configure Input and Output of the Model](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_IE_DG_Integrate_with_customer_application_new_API.html#step-2-optional-configure-input-and-output-of-the-model), in [Integrate Inference Engine](https://docs.openvino.ai/latest/openvino_docs_IE_DG_Integrate_with_customer_application_new_API.html#integrate-inference-engine).

Please add the following code before `executable_network`:

```
# Get names of the input blob
input_blob_name = next(iter(network.input_info))
# Set input precision
network.input_info[input_blob_name].precision = 'FP16'
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found that I didn't need to change FP32 to FP16 in my inference engine code.

And my MYRIAD device could work normally, appreciate!